# How do I override the title of a bookmark for a web page?

Tags: html, seo, title, bookmarks

When adding a bookmark or favorite the browser uses the TITLE tag of the page to automatically populate the title of the bookmark. However, my web pages use SEO-friendly titles which are not really user-friendly. Is there a method to override the title when the browser makes a bookmark?

I am aware that I can create a link on the page that calls javascript:

```
javascript:window.external.addFavorite("url","custom title");
```

But is is possible to do something similar when a user uses the menu or hotkey to create a bookmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see how that would be possible. The browser takes the Title loaded, which is the Title displayed on the top of the page. When saving a bookmark, it doesnt go through the code. It just adds the URL and takes the site Title.

You could check if the "bookmark"-pressing triggers a javascript event, though, i think it woudlnt be cross-browser :)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

> However, my web pages use SEO-friendly titles which are not really user-friendly

This is what you need to fix. Your page titles should be user friendly.

To be honest, if you're doing it right SEO and User friendly titles should be synonymous... can you post some examples as to why you feel the need for them to be so different?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am at the whim of senior executives and outside consultants that mandate that the titles geared toward SEO. Yes, it's gaming the system and is horrendous. /sigh

Comment: Your execs need to decide who your audience is: users or search engines.

Comment: They decided. Search engines. Users don't see us if we get pushed down page 1 of The Google.

Comment: `SEO and User friendly titles should be synonymous` - Not really. User friendly titles would be short to not clutter the bookmark bar or folder, however it's better to have a detailed title show up in Google Search (not just for SEO), but for the user to know what the page is about before clicking it.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. there are other reasons you might want to override the bookmark title which can't be solved this way